# Compute date difference between rows considering different groups inside dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with some information from treatments applied to animals in `R`. First I would like to describe the structure of my information (I will add the `dput()` version in the end). My data is `DF` and it looks like this:

```
  Treatment_ID Start_Date      Valid
1         0031 2011-05-01 2011-05-30
2         0031 2011-05-01 2011-06-30
3         0045 2012-02-01 2012-03-01
4         0057 2012-04-01 2012-04-30
5         0057 2012-04-01 2012-05-30
6         0098 2012-10-01 2012-10-30
```

It has 56 rows and three variables `Treatment_ID` (5 types of treatments), `Start_Date` (Date of start of treatment) and `Valid` (Final date of the treatment). For example the `Treatment_ID` `0031` has two observations because this started on May 2011 and finished on June 2011. Then a new treatment `0045`started on February 2012 and finished on March 2012 (Only one observation). The same structure applies for all the groups inside `DF`. I need to compute the difference of months between each treatment and behind each treatment using some conditions. I will use the first two treatments to show this:

```
  Treatment_ID Start_Date      Valid
1         0031 2011-05-01 2011-05-30
2         0031 2011-05-01 2011-06-30
3         0045 2012-02-01 2012-03-01
4         0057 2012-04-01 2012-04-30
```

For this example, I have two rows for the first treatment where the `Treatment_Id` variable is equal. When that occurs the difference in months for the variable `Valid` must be calculated. When a new treatment appears then the difference in months between `Start_Date` and `Valid` must be calculated. Notice that when a treatment has more than one observation the difference is gotten by using `Valid` variable for the observations in that group but when the `Treatment_Id` changes therefore the difference must be obtained by using `Start_Date` and `Valid` variables. To get this variable `Break_Months` I used the next structure:

```
DF$Break_Months=NA

for(i in c(2:(length(DF$Break_Months))))
{
  DF$Break_Months[i]=ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[i]==DF$Treatment_ID[i-1],round(as.numeric(DF$Valid[i]-DF$Valid[i-1])/30,0),
                            round(as.numeric(DF$Start_Date[i]-DF$Valid[i-1])/30,0))
}
```

This `for` when the `Treatment_Id` are equal computes the difference between the actual row and the previous with `Valid` variable and when they are different the difference is computed using `Start_Date` and `Valid`. The first value of `Break_Months` is `NA` because there is not a previous value to compare. The problem appeared in the end of `DF` when I used the previous lines of code.

```
   Treatment_ID Start_Date      Valid Break_Months
47         0098 2012-10-01 2016-07-30            1
48         0098 2012-10-01 2016-08-31            1
49         0031 2016-09-01 2016-09-30            0
50         0031 2016-09-01 2016-10-30            1
51         0031 2016-09-01 2016-11-30            1
52         0031 2016-09-01 2016-12-30            1
53         0031 2016-09-01 2017-01-30            1
54         0031 2016-09-01 2017-03-02            1
55         0031 2016-09-01 2017-03-30            1
56         0012 2017-03-01 2017-03-30           -1
```

The `Treatment_Id` `0012` has only one observation because it is new and the `Valid` date is the same that the last observation of treatment `0031`. Because the `Treatment_Id` `0031` has been used in other months then difference is computed with the previous observations inside the treatment. In the case of `0012` this is not possible because the `Valid` date of this is the same that the last observation of `0031` and `0012` does not have more observations because it is new. When that happens the comparison must be done with the last observation of the group previous to `0031` this is `0098`. By using the concept due to `0012` is not equal to `0098` the `Break_Months` is computed by the difference between `2017-03-01` (`Start_Date`) and `2016-08-31` (`Valid`) giving a value of `6` by the same mechanic in the `for` structure and not `-1`.

My question is related to how to incorporate this consideration inside the `for`. It has been very complex to try to do this because I do not know how to integrate a comparison related to the date (if they are equal as in he example) and looking for the previous group before the one that contains the same date. I have tried using `lag` function from `dplyr` package to avoid the `for` but the results are not the same. The `dput()` version of `DF` is the next:

```
DF<-structure(list(Treatment_ID = c("0031", "0031", "0045", "0057", 
"0057", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", 
"0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", 
"0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", 
"0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", 
"0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", 
"0098", "0098", "0098", "0098", "0031", "0031", "0031", "0031", 
"0031", "0031", "0031", "0012"), Start_Date = structure(c(1304208000, 
1304208000, 1328054400, 1333238400, 1333238400, 1349049600, 1349049600, 
1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 
1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 
1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 
1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 
1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 
1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 
1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1349049600, 1472688000, 
1472688000, 1472688000, 1472688000, 1472688000, 1472688000, 1472688000, 
1488326400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Valid = structure(c(1306713600, 1309392000, 1330560000, 1335744000, 
    1338336000, 1351555200, 1354233600, 1356825600, 1359504000, 
    1362182400, 1364601600, 1367280000, 1369872000, 1372550400, 
    1375142400, 1377820800, 1380499200, 1383091200, 1385769600, 
    1388361600, 1391040000, 1393718400, 1396137600, 1398816000, 
    1401408000, 1404086400, 1412035200, 1414627200, 1417305600, 
    1419897600, 1422576000, 1425254400, 1427673600, 1432944000, 
    1435622400, 1440892800, 1443571200, 1446163200, 1448841600, 
    1451433600, 1454112000, 1456790400, 1459296000, 1461974400, 
    1464566400, 1467244800, 1469836800, 1472601600, 1475193600, 
    1477785600, 1480464000, 1483056000, 1485734400, 1488412800, 
    1490832000, 1490832000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), .Names = c("Treatment_ID", 
"Start_Date", "Valid"), row.names = c(NA, -56L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks for your help.

**Update**
One of these solutions worked perfect. Now I have a little issue when I have to compute a similar variables. First I compute the variable `Elapsed` that is the difference between `Valid` and `Start_Date`. I use the next code:

```
DF$Elapsed=round(as.numeric(DF$Valid-DF$Start_Date)/30,0)
```

Then, the dilemma appears. I have to compute the next two variables `Last1` and `Last2`. I use the next code for this:

```
#Compute Last1
DF$Last1=NA
DF$Last1[1]=0
for(j in c(2:length(DF$Last1)))
{
  DF$Last1[j]=ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[j]==DF$Treatment_ID[j-1],DF$Last1[j-1],
                     ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[j]!=DF$Treatment_ID[j-1],DF$Elapsed[j-1],0))
}
```

The code worked parcially because I have a similar problem related to the variable `Break_Months`. In this case because `0031` and `0012` have the same `Valid` value the comparison of `Treatment_Id` must not be done with the last value of `0031` where 7 is assigned due to the logic of the loop (variable `Elapsed`). In this case the correct value is 48 because the comparison must be structured with the last observation of group `0098` then we get the 48. I have tried to modify with `last_obs_index` but I can not get the correct result.

```
   Treatment_ID Start_Date      Valid Break_Months Elapsed Last1
47         0098 2012-10-01 2016-07-30            1      47     2
48         0098 2012-10-01 2016-08-31            1      48     2
49         0031 2016-09-01 2016-09-30            0       1    48
50         0031 2016-09-01 2016-10-30            1       2    48
51         0031 2016-09-01 2016-11-30            1       3    48
52         0031 2016-09-01 2016-12-30            1       4    48
53         0031 2016-09-01 2017-01-30            1       5    48
54         0031 2016-09-01 2017-03-02            1       6    48
55         0031 2016-09-01 2017-03-30            1       7    48
56         0012 2017-03-01 2017-03-30            6       1     7
```

For the variable `Last2` I use the next code:

```
#Compute Last2
DF$Last2=NA
DF$Last2[1]=0
for(k in c(2:length(DF$Last2)))
{
  DF$Last2[k]=ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[k]==DF$Treatment_ID[k-1],DF$Last2[k-1],
                     ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[k]!=DF$Treatment_ID[k-1],DF$Break_Months[k],0))
}
```

In this case it seems that worked but that is not true. Despite the fact that 6 is correct, the comparison is not well defined because `0012` and `0031` has the same `Valid` date and the optimal comparison is using the last observation of `0098` group.Therefore, the value of `Break_Months` is assigned. Again I could not fix the loop with the proper logic defined with `last_obs_index`.

```
   Treatment_ID Start_Date      Valid Break_Months Elapsed Last1 Last2
47         0098 2012-10-01 2016-07-30            1      47     2     4
48         0098 2012-10-01 2016-08-31            1      48     2     4
49         0031 2016-09-01 2016-09-30            0       1    48     0
50         0031 2016-09-01 2016-10-30            1       2    48     0
51         0031 2016-09-01 2016-11-30            1       3    48     0
52         0031 2016-09-01 2016-12-30            1       4    48     0
53         0031 2016-09-01 2017-01-30            1       5    48     0
54         0031 2016-09-01 2017-03-02            1       6    48     0
55         0031 2016-09-01 2017-03-30            1       7    48     0
56         0012 2017-03-01 2017-03-30            6       1     7     6
```

Thanks for all the help this time, would it be possible to get advice about how to adapt the loops to get the comparisons in the right way.

Comment: Based on the code you provide the first and only observation for `Treatment_ID == 0045` has `Break_Months == 7`, shouldn't that be `1` for the difference between `2012-02-01` and `2012-03-01`? So does the `for` loop not work in other places besides the end?

Comment: In the sample data, treatment 0012 starts a whole month before treatment 0031 ends.  So isn't the -1 for the last entry the correct result?

Comment: Dear @johnckane  @lebelinoz in the sample both 0012 and 0031 are Valid to 2017-03-30 when that happens the difference needs to be done with the last observation of previous group 0098. Then, as 0012 and 0098 are different we compute `Start_Date` - `Valid` giving 6 and no other value. That is the problem in my loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in a `for` loop you'll need to add an additional criteria to your calculation when the value of `Treatment_ID` is different from the previous observation.

If the value of `Treatment_ID` is not the same as the previous observation, compute the difference between `Start_Date` for this observation and the value of `Valid` for the last observation of the most recent `Treatment_ID` where the last value of `Valid` is also different.

To do this you need to know the indices of `DF` where the values of `Treatment_ID` change and the values of `Valid` change. You'll need the `Lag` function from `Hmisc`

```
library(Hmisc)
new_obs_index <- which(DF$Treatment_ID != Lag(DF$Treatment_ID,1) & DF$Valid != Lag(DF$Valid))
```

This provides the index of where the new observations start, we actually want the index of the last observation for the last `Treatment_ID` prior to this.

```
last_obs_index <- new_obs_index - 1
```

These are the indices of the values of `Valid` that meet the criteria of last observation for `Treatment_ID` such that the value of `Valid` changes in the next observation as well.

Then in the `for` loop when the value of `Treatment_ID` changes subtract the difference between `Start` and the most recent value of `Valid` that meets our criteria. We accomplish this by specifying we want

```
DF$Valid[last_obs_index[max(which(last_obs_index < i))]]
```

So the `for` loop looks like this:

```
for(i in c(2:(length(DF$Break_Months)))){
  DF$Break_Months[i]=ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[i]==DF$Treatment_ID[i-1],
round(as.numeric(DF$Valid[i]-DF$Valid[i-1])/30,0),round(as.numeric(DF$Start_Date[i]-DF$Valid[last_obs_index[max(which(last_obs_index < i))]])/30,0))
}
```

This gives the desired result in the last observation in DF.

```
   Treatment_ID Start_Date      Valid Break_Months
51         0031 2016-09-01 2016-11-30            1
52         0031 2016-09-01 2016-12-30            1
53         0031 2016-09-01 2017-01-30            1
54         0031 2016-09-01 2017-03-02            1
55         0031 2016-09-01 2017-03-30            1
56         0012 2017-03-01 2017-03-30            6
```

So altogether, the necessary code to implement is

```
library(Hmisc)
new_obs_index <- which(DF$Treatment_ID != Lag(DF$Treatment_ID,1) & DF$Valid != Lag(DF$Valid))
last_obs_index <- new_obs_index - 1 
for(i in c(2:(length(DF$Break_Months)))){
DF$Break_Months[i]=ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[i]==DF$Treatment_ID[i-1],round(as.numeric(DF$Valid[i]-DF$Valid[i-1])/30,0),round(as.numeric(DF$Start_Date[i]-DF$Valid[last_obs_index[max(which(last_obs_index < i))]])/30,0))
}
```

**UPDATE**
For the variable `Last1` you can access the value you desire using the vector `last_obs_index` using this syntax:

```
for(j in c(2:length(DF$Last1))){
DF$Last1[j]=ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[j]==DF$Treatment_ID[j-1],DF$Last1[j-1],ifelse(DF$Treatment_ID[j]!=DF$Treatment_ID[j-1],DF$Elapsed[last_obs_index[max(which(last_obs_index < i))]],0))}
```

For the variable `Last2` if I understand you correctly I think your implementation will always give the answer you want. I think a new treatment value is sufficient to use the value of `Break_Months` and you don't also need a different value of `Valid` to use it.

Comment: Dear @johnckane your solution worked for me. I will accept your answer but I made an update because I had a similar problem where the same logic you used need to be incorporated inside new loops. Could you please help with this additional consideration. Thanks a lot of.

Comment: just updated my response, I don't think you need to alter the syntax for the `Last2` variable.

Comment: Thanks @johnckane but I would like to keep inside the loop for `Last2` the same logic of the comparison with `last_obs_index` because new treatments could appear (more than two) with the same `Valid` date. Is it possible? Your solution is fantastic.

Comment: Yes, can you provide an example of data where what you currently do won't work? I'm having trouble following.

Comment: I will add an example later @johnckane meanwhile I will accept your answer. Thanks for your help and I hope with the new example you can help me with that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method making use of a few extra dplyr functions like `lag` and `if_else`. It works out the comparison date (kept here for a sanity check), subtracts the previous Valid date from this, and then converts to rounded number of "months" (30 day periods).

```
library(dplyr)

  mutate(DF,
    comparison_date = if_else(Treatment_ID == lag(Treatment_ID), Valid, Start_Date),
    Break_Months = difftime(comparison_date, lag(Valid), units = "days"),
    Break_Months = as.numeric(round(Break_Months / 30)))

#>    Treatment_ID Start_Date      Valid comparison_date Break_Months
#> 1          0031 2011-05-01 2011-05-30            <NA>           NA
#> 2          0031 2011-05-01 2011-06-30      2011-06-30            1
#> 3          0045 2012-02-01 2012-03-01      2012-02-01            7
#> 4          0057 2012-04-01 2012-04-30      2012-04-01            1
#> 5          0057 2012-04-01 2012-05-30      2012-05-30            1
#> 6          0098 2012-10-01 2012-10-30      2012-10-01            4
#> 7          0098 2012-10-01 2012-11-30      2012-11-30            1
#> 8          0098 2012-10-01 2012-12-30      2012-12-30            1
#> 9          0098 2012-10-01 2013-01-30      2013-01-30            1
#> 10         0098 2012-10-01 2013-03-02      2013-03-02            1
...
```